# Using a double cycle

Tags: r, function, lapply, cycle

I have a dataframe **pif** which has information about some investition funds and a list **names** which contains the names of said funds (or simply **pif**'s variable names):

```
names
 [1] mercury_stock  vtb_bric ...
```

et cetera.

Now I need to calculate some essential information. My desired output are dataframes containing yields for each fund, which I then bind together using `cbind`.

For this operation I already have a cycle function:

```
i=c(1:1584)
pif<-cbind(i, pif)
for ( i in 2:1584)
{
d_mercury_stock[i] = (pif$mercury_stock[i] - pif$mercury_stock[i-1])/pif$mercury_stock[i-1]
d_vtb_bric[i] = (pif$vtb_bric[i] - pif$vtb_bric[i-1])/pif$vtb_bric[i-1]
...
}

yield<-cbind(d_mercury_stock, d_vtb_bric, ...)
```

It works completely fine, but I need to manually perform this function to get results for every fund - and the dataframe has over 30, meaning that I should copy and paste the same function thirty times.

The best solution would be a second cycle which runs my function, using elements of the list **names** and somehow inserting each variable there.

Unfortunately I'm unable to do that since I'm relatively new to loops and repeating fuctions. I suspect that either `lapply`/`sapply` or a custom function could be a solution here.
What could you advise?

Comment: You could add a mock data.frame to make the code reproducible and easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the answer is really simple. Posting it here in case other users stumble upon the same problem.

```
for (j in 1:ncol(pif))
  for ( i in 2:1584)
  {
   yield[i,j] = (pif[i,j] - pif[i-1,j])/pif[i-1,j]
  }
```

The output is an already-compiled matrix which only lacks proper variable names.